# How to add navigation drawer to an exisiting activity/layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add navigation drawer to this layout. It currently has a Bottom Navigation View and a relative layout to hold fragment.
Problem is I can't make the root layout a Drawer Layout coz it opts out the fragment container relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="deb.com.firebasedemo.HomePage"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="#054ec5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_state_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_state_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried something like this. Putting drawer layout inside the relative layout and navigation view.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="deb.com.firebasedemo.HomePage"
    >

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="start">


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="#054ec5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_state_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_state_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">
    </RelativeLayout>











</RelativeLayout>
```

But it's not working :( .. The navigation drawer won't show up.
I need some help here.

Comment: I just figured it out. I have to put drawer layout as the root layout and put the NavigationView outside relative layout and inside drawer layout. That solved my issue. :)